# Google maps API error "refused to load font"

Tags: google-maps-api-3, angular, ionic2

I am using Google maps in my angular2/Ionic2 app and I get the following error:

> js?libraries=geometry,drawing,places:79 Refused to load the font
>   'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/isZ-wbCXNKAbnjo6_TwHThJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "font-src 'self' data:".

What is this error, and how can I fix it?

My `index.html` has:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="font-src 'self' data:; img-src * data:; default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'">

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,drawing,places"></script>
```

Removing the `meta` tag solves the problem, but I am not sure what it does and whether I should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about inline javascript, but inline style tags. Either you have them (probably not), or you are using something (possibly a jquery plugin) that is adding them. Based from this [blog](https://content-security-policy.com/), you ned to enable it by adding the configuration from https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-content-security-policy#options into your `config/environment.js`.

The default `contentSecurityPolicy` value is:

```
 contentSecurityPolicy: {
    'default-src': ["'none'"],
    'script-src':  ["'self'"],
    'font-src':    ["'self'"],
    'connect-src': ["'self'"],
    'img-src':     ["'self'"],
    'style-src':   ["'self'"],
    'media-src':   ["'self'"]
  }
```

Check these related links: [Violating Content Security Policy directive after ember-cli 0.0.47 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192316/violating-content-security-policy-directive-after-ember-cli-0-0-47-upgrade) and ["[Report Only] Refused to load the font..." error message on console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572418/report-only-refused-to-load-the-font-error-message-on-console)